# Return type and value of init

Tags: python

I am confused in return type and value of`__init__()` in Python.

Does `__init__()` return value or else and what is return type of`__init__()`?

Comment: Please include some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**init** doesn't and shouldn't return any thing other than None.  The purpose of **init**, as its name says, is to initialize attributes.

You can actually try to return None in init but not returning anything would by default return None in Python.

Answer (score 0):

While being treated specially - it's automagically called with the newly created instance at instanciation time -, `__init__` is by itself just an ordinary Python function, so it implicitely returns `None` unless you try to explicitely return something else... But then you will find out (at call time) that it's not allowed to return anything than `None`, so you can safely assume it won't return anything else ;)